# Is there any method to identify limit cycle in non-linear second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I am working with a **second-order** **non-linear differential equation** and I have a very good guess that it should have a stable **limit cycle** (because of the physics involved in the phenomena which is described by these differential equation). I was wondering whether there is a general method for the above purpose!

Comment: Show me the equation. As I had a nonlinear second order ode which depending on the parameters yielded a limit cycle as determined by the theorem outlined by the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can apply the **Poincare-Bendixson Theorem** to show there is a periodic orbit, or you can use **Bendixsons Negative Criterion** to show that no such periodic orbit exists.